# CPTMutablePlotRange - Can't set length and location

Tags: xcode, swift, core-plot

I am trying to get familiar with the CorePlot library and I want to create a sample app using Swift. As I am trying to set the ranges for my axis I stumbled accross [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324882/coreplot-in-swift-change-starting-value-of-axis-to-1), and I am trying to follow it!

However, my Xcode gives me an error when I come to line 3:

```
xRange.length = 10.0
```

Xcode states that there is no such member. However, there is a member called lengthDouble, which cannot be set. The same behaviour can be observerd with the location parameter.

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing here?

Comment: See the comments on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25170579/coreplot-swift-method-not-found) also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an issue regarding Objective-C's NSDecimal type which is not available in Swift. I found this work around: http://blog.alwold.com/2014/09/03/coreplot-nsdecimal-and-swift/